# Create pandas dataframe from json objects

Tags: python, json, pandas

I finally have output of data I need from a file with many json objects but I need some help with converting the below output into a single dataframe as it loops through the data. Here is the code to produce the output including a sample of what the output looks like:

original data:

```
{
"zipcode":"08989",
"current"{"canwc":null,"cig":4900,"class":"observation","clds":"OVC","day_ind":"D","dewpt":19,"expireTimeGMT":1385486700,"feels_like":34,"gust":null,"hi":37,"humidex":null,"icon_code":26,"icon_extd":2600,"max_temp":37,"wxMan":"wx1111"},
"triggers":[53,31,9,21,48,7,40,178,55,179,176,26,103,175,33,51,20,57,112,30,50,113]
}
{
"zipcode":"08990",
"current":{"canwc":null,"cig":4900,"class":"observation","clds":"OVC","day_ind":"D","dewpt":19,"expireTimeGMT":1385486700,"feels_like":34,"gust":null,"hi":37,"humidex":null,"icon_code":26,"icon_extd":2600,"max_temp":37, "wxMan":"wx1111"},
"triggers":[53,31,9,21,48,7,40,178,55,179,176,26,103,175,33,51,20,57,112,30,50,113]
}

def lines_per_n(f, n):
    for line in f:
        yield ''.join(chain([line], itertools.islice(f, n - 1)))

for fin in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    with open(fin) as f:
        for chunk in lines_per_n(f, 5):
            try:
                jfile = json.loads(chunk)
                zipcode = jfile['zipcode']
                datetime = jfile['current']['proc_time']
                triggers = jfile['triggers']
                print pd.Series(jfile['zipcode']), 
                      pd.Series(jfile['current']['proc_time']),\
                      jfile['triggers']          
            except ValueError, e:
                pass
            else:
                pass
```

Sample output I get when I run the above which I would like to store in a pandas dataframe as 3 columns.

```
08988 20131126102946 []
08989 20131126102946 [53, 31, 9, 21, 48, 7, 40, 178, 55, 179]
08988 20131126102946 []
08989 20131126102946 [53, 31, 9, 21, 48, 7, 40, 178, 55, 179]
00544 20131126102946 [178, 30, 176, 103, 179, 112, 21, 20, 48]
```

So the below code seems a lot closer in that it gives me a funky df if I pass the in the list and Transpose the df. Any idea on how I can get this reshaped properly?

```
def series_chunk(chunk):
    jfile = json.loads(chunk)
    zipcode = jfile['zipcode']
    datetime = jfile['current']['proc_time']
    triggers = jfile['triggers']
    return jfile['zipcode'],\
            jfile['current']['proc_time'],\
            jfile['triggers']

for fin in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    with open(fin) as f:
        for chunk in lines_per_n(f, 7):
            df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(series_chunk(chunk)))
            print df1.T

[u'08988', u'20131126102946', []]
[u'08989', u'20131126102946', [53, 31, 9, 21, 48, 7, 40, 178, 55, 179]]
[u'08988', u'20131126102946', []]
[u'08989', u'20131126102946', [53, 31, 9, 21, 48, 7, 40, 178, 55, 179]]
```

Dataframe:

```
   0               1   2
0  08988  20131126102946  []
       0               1                                                  2
0  08989  20131126102946  [53, 31, 9, 21, 48, 7, 40, 178, 55, 179, 176, ...
       0               1   2
0  08988  20131126102946  []
       0               1                                                  2
0  08989  20131126102946  [53, 31, 9, 21, 48, 7, 40, 178, 55, 179, 176, ...
```

Here is my final code and output. How do I capture each dataframe it creates through the loop and concatenate them on the fly as one dataframe object?

```
for fin in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    with open(fin) as f:
        print pd.concat([series_chunk(chunk) for chunk in lines_per_n(f, 7)], axis=1).T

       0               1                                                  2
0  08988  20131126102946                                                 []
1  08989  20131126102946  [53, 31, 9, 21, 48, 7, 40, 178, 55, 179, 176, ...
       0               1                                                  2
0  08988  20131126102946                                                 []
1  08989  20131126102946  [53, 31, 9, 21, 48, 7, 40, 178, 55, 179, 176, ...
```

Comment: What is the output you *want*?

Comment: exactly as you have it in your read_csv dataframe method with the regex. Just 3 columns with the keys and values from the specified 3 keys.

Comment: I think you're going to be able to wrap this with a concat, something like: pd.concat([series_chunk(chunk) for chunk in lines_per_n(f, 5)]), where series_chunk is the function returning each row as a Series (the bit in the try/except block).

Comment: @AndyHayden Thank you for the help. I'm a little stuck with the final step of concatenating into a df object. I've updated my code and output. Would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Appended to my answer, should get you on the right track.

Comment: Thank you so much, extremely helpful. I'm getting the following error though: "Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, u'20131126102946' was passed"

Comment: there was a typo when I created the Series, missing [].

Comment: Thank you again. Just trying to wrangle the final output I'm getting now (appended). I was expecting df.T to work but it didn't do transpose columns and rows.

Comment: More bugs from me, you need to use concat with axis=1, updated my answer, sorry!

Comment: You are a total rock-star! Thank you! Accepted and upvoted answer.

Comment: @AndyHayden can I trouble you for one final question before I put this to rest. This is probably incredibly simple but my iteration skills are a little weak. How would concat each dataframe it creates in the loop as one object?

Comment: One way is to concat them together, tweaked...

Comment: I'm not sure how to correctly implement your suggestion. Are you recommending to use either append or concat? I get how the first concat we have will concat the chunks but it seems like now I have to wrap the whole thing in another concat.

Comment: I think you can't do a list comprehension with a with inside it so I appended result to a list before concat-ing... I guess you could pull out the file_to_series as another function.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

###Note: For those of you arriving at this question looking to parse json into pandas, if you do have *valid* json (this question doesn't) then you should use pandas [`read_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.read_json.html) function:

```
# can either pass string of the json, or a filepath to a file with valid json
In [99]: pd.read_json('[{"A": 1, "B": 2}, {"A": 3, "B": 4}]')
Out[99]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

Check out the [IO part of the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#json) for several examples, arguments you can pass to this function, as well as ways to normalize less structured json.

*If you don't have valid json*, it's often efficient to munge the string before reading in as json, for example [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20038973/1240268).

If you have several json files you should concat the DataFrames together (similar to in this answer):

```
pd.concat([pd.read_json(file) for file in ...], ignore_index=True)
```

###Original answer for this example:

Use a lookbehind in the regex for the separator passed to read_csv:

```
In [11]: df = pd.read_csv('foo.csv', sep='(?<!,)\s', header=None)

In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
       0               1                                                  2
0   8988  20131126102946                                                 []
1   8989  20131126102946  [53, 31, 9, 21, 48, 7, 40, 178, 55, 179, 176, ...
2   8988  20131126102946                                                 []
3   8989  20131126102946  [53, 31, 9, 21, 48, 7, 40, 178, 55, 179, 176, ...
4    544  20131126102946  [178, 30, 176, 103, 179, 112, 21, 20, 48, 7, 5...
5    601  20131126094911                                                 []
6    602  20131126101056                                                 []
7    603  20131126101056                                                 []
8    604  20131126101056                                                 []
9    544  20131126102946  [178, 30, 176, 103, 179, 112, 21, 20, 48, 7, 5...
10   601  20131126094911                                                 []
11   602  20131126101056                                                 []
12   603  20131126101056                                                 []
13   604  20131126101056                                                 []

[14 rows x 3 columns]
```

As mentioned in the comments you may be able to do this more directly by concat several Series together... It's also going to be a little easier to follow:

```
def series_chunk(chunk):
    jfile = json.loads(chunk)
    zipcode = jfile['zipcode']
    datetime = jfile['current']['proc_time']
    triggers = jfile['triggers']
    return pd.Series([jfile['zipcode'], jfile['current']['proc_time'], jfile['triggers']])

dfs = []
for fin in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    with open(fin) as f:
        df = pd.concat([series_chunk(chunk) for chunk in lines_per_n(f, 5)], axis=1)
        dfs.append(dfs)

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

*Note: You can also move the try/except into `series_chunk`.*

Comment: But what if I'm not working from a csv? I need to process a large file of json objects and then produce values from the three keys in my question. I'm trying to bring the data into a dataframe for further processing.

Comment: @prometheus2305 this is how to create a DataFrame from the output you gave (although not strictly a "csv"!). I suspect it's possible for you to concat some objects together more directly, but difficult without a [short example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Thank you. I've added all of the code and sample data. Would love to be able to concat the object outputs into a dataframe somehow. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
import json
import pandas as pd
```

Approach - 1 (Simple json to dataframe)

```
df = pd.read_json('data/simple.json')
```

Approach - 2 (Nested json to dataframe)

```
data = []
with open('data.json','r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        row = json.loads(line)
        data.append(row)
data = json.loads(json.dumps(data))
df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path =['annotation'], meta=['content', 'extras'])
```