# How do I turn this json object into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a csv file that I turn into a json so that I can turn it into a panda data-frame.

Here is my code,

```
def create_png():

    f = open('sticks.csv', 'r')
    reader = csv.DictReader( f, fieldnames = ("xstk", "stk") )
    out = json.dumps( [row for row in reader ] )
    print out

    df = DataFrame([
        #TODO
    ])
```

The line 'print out' prints out "[{"xstk": "1", "stk": "0"}, {"xstk": "0", "stk": "1"}, {"xstk": "1", "stk": "0"}]"

So what can I put into #TODO to make the code run and turn this into a simple two column dataframe? I have looked at [Create pandas dataframe from json objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643437/create-pandas-dataframe-from-json-objects) but it is a complicated example.

Comment: Why not just read it directly in as a csv (using `pandas.read_csv`)?

Comment: Also, I updated my answer to that question you link to (it didn't really answer the headline question - how to read in json). Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply read the string of the json in directly to [`read_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.read_json.html):

```
In [11]: pd.read_json('[{"xstk": "1", "stk": "0"}, {"xstk": "0", "stk": "1"}, {"xstk": "1", "stk": "0"}]')
Out[11]:
   stk  xstk
0    0     1
1    1     0
2    0     1
```

However, if you already have a csv you should really read it in directly using [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('sticks.csv', names=["xstk", "stk"])
```