# Reading Json file as Pandas Dataframe error

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a Json file as follows. It's a list of dicts.

```
[{"city": "ab", "trips": 4, "date": "2014-01-25", "value": 4.7, "price": 1.1, "request_date": "2014-06-17", "medium": "iPhone", "%price": 15.4, "type": true, "Weekly_pct": 46.2, "avg_dist": 3.67, "avg_price": 5.0}, {"city": "bc", "trips": 0, "date": "2014-01-29", "value": 5.0, "price": 1.0, "request_date": "2014-05-05", "medium": "Android", "%price": 0.0, "type": false, "weekly_pct": 50.0, "avg_dist": 8.26, "avg_price": 5.0}.....]
```

When I read this using this:

```
data=pd.read_json('dataset.json')
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: Expected object or value

I tried this too:

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open('dataset.json') as f:
    data = literal_eval(f.read())

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

It gives the following error:

> ValueError: malformed string

Edit:

Even Json.loads doesn't work. Tried this:

```
import json
data=json.loads('dataset.json')
```

> ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

The Json file is 13.5MB but it seems to have huge amounts of data.

Comment: Does `json.loads` work? (`import json` first...)

Comment: No. I tried that it gave me this error. Check Edit.

Comment: I think you might benefit from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20644150/5276797

Answer (score 17):

I think you can use modul `json` for reading `file.json` and then `DataFrame constructor`:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open('file.json') as f:
   data = json.load(f)
print data
[{u'city': u'ab', u'medium': u'iPhone', u'request_date': u'2014-06-17', u'price': 1.1, u'Weekly_pct': 46.2, u'value': 4.7, u'%price': 15.4, u'avg_price': 5.0, u'date': u'2014-01-25', u'avg_dist': 3.67, u'type': True, u'trips': 4}, {u'city': u'bc', u'medium': u'Android', u'request_date': u'2014-05-05', u'price': 1.0, u'weekly_pct': 50.0, u'value': 5.0, u'%price': 0.0, u'avg_price': 5.0, u'date': u'2014-01-29', u'avg_dist': 8.26, u'type': False, u'trips': 0}]

print pd.DataFrame(data)

   %price  Weekly_pct  avg_dist  avg_price city        date   medium  price  \
0    15.4        46.2      3.67        5.0   ab  2014-01-25   iPhone    1.1   
1     0.0         NaN      8.26        5.0   bc  2014-01-29  Android    1.0   

  request_date  trips   type  value  weekly_pct  
0   2014-06-17      4   True    4.7         NaN  
1   2014-05-05      0  False    5.0        50.0
```

Comment: I think the example OP gave works, and that the error is buried somewhere in the large file...

Comment: Hmmm,  I get first error (`ValueError: Expected object or value`) and second error (`ValueError: malformed string`)  too with sample. But my solution works very well.

Comment: ok. I just did what @jezrael suggested. And it worked. However my column order is different. Like city should be first column but its coming in different order as he is getting too. Any idea how to get same order of column names?

Comment: @jezrael any idea why `read_json` would fail? And why your solution works? Even `json.loads` (with an s) fails...

Comment: Yes. Json.loads fails, read_json fails and even ujson.load fails. I had tried all these three and it failed but json.load works

Comment: I think it fails, because list of dictionaries in `json` file. It is valid `json`, but seems `read_json` doesnt support these type of json.

Comment: Sorry, there is something wrong? Why you unaccept? Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same error. Turns out it couldn't find the file. I modified the path and `pd.read_json` worked fine. As for `json.loads`, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2835672/8119275) might be helpful.

Comment: had the same error because I moved the jupyter notebook and jupyter would not adapt the file path. Pandas is returning the worst error message possible here.

Answer (score 8):

You need to indicate to Pandas that "records" formatting (where the JSON appears like a list of dictionaries) is used in `datasets.json`.

```
res = pd.read_json('input/dataset.json', orient='records')

print(res.iloc[:, :5])
   %price  Weekly_pct  avg_dist  avg_price city
0    15.4        46.2      3.67          5   ab
1     0.0         NaN      8.26          5   bc
```

Answer (score 5):

The following worked for me when pd.read_json failed:
open file, load with normal json.load, then load into a pandas dataframe.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import json

    openfile=open('file.json')
    jsondata=json.load(openfile)
    df=pd.DataFrame(jsondata)

    openfile.close()
    print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a problem with the path. The path I had to use depended on the directory from where I run the python file. Maybe try to 'cd' into the directory of your python file and then `data=pd.read_json('dataset.json')` should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the parameter `lines=True` to make it work, e.g:

```
pd.read_json("dataset.json", lines=True)
```

Alternatively you could do it like this:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open("dataset.json") as f:
  df = pd.DataFrame([json.loads(l) for l in f.readlines()])
print(df)  # Shows data frame as expected
```