# Import JSON into pandas dataframe error

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a JSON file as follows. I want to import it as pandas dataframe. My data was exported from MySQL workbench.

```
[
  {
    "id" : 1,
    "reviewer_id" : 5,
    "reviewed_date" : "2010-07-25 21:47:40",
    "description" : "วันนี้  ผมพาท่านผู้อ่านมาลิ้มลองสเต๊กราคาย่อมเยาว์ แถวย่านพัฒนาการกันนะครับ\r\nร้าน Bkk Steak ที่พัฒนาการ 61 นี้ เปิดเมื่อปี 2551 ตอนนั้นยังเป็นห้องแถวห้องเดียว ไม่มีแอร์ด้วย จำได้ว่าที่ผมไปกินครั้งแรก ร้านบอกว่าเปิดถึงเที่ยงคืน!  (จะว่าไปก็ การกินของหนักๆ อย่างสเต๊กในเวลาดึกดื่นขนาดนี้ ไม่เป็นผลดีต่อสุขภาพแน่ๆ)  หลังๆ จึงร่นระยะเวลามาเปิดถึง 4 ทุ่มครึ่งแทน (ก็ยังดึกอยู่ดี) ด้วยรสชาติอาหารที่ดี ในราคาที่ถือว่าคุ้มค่ามาก (เริ่มต้นที่ 69 บาท) ทำให้มีลูกค้ามาทานอย่างต่อเนื่อง และภายในเวลาไม่ถึงปี ร้าน Bkk Steak ก็ย้ายจากห้องแถวเดิม ไปเปิดใหม่เป็นห้องแถว 2 คูหาฝั่งตรงข้ามแทน\r\n\r\nโฉมใหม่ของ Bkk Steak คือร้าน 2 คูหา ติดแอร์ แต่งร้านแบบเรียบง่าย ดูโปร่งและสะอาดตา รอบๆ ร้านมีภาพของสเต๊กเมนูต่างๆ พนักงานต้อนรับส่วนใหญ่เป็นผู้ชายครับ\r\n\r\nรายการอาหารในเมนูมีภาพประกอบเกือบทั้งหมด เริ่มต้นจากออเดิร์ฟเช่น ซุปครีมเห็ด (25 บาท)  กุ้งทอดสอดไส้ชีส (59 บาท) และสลัดทูน่า (49 บาท)  ส่วนพระเอกที่เป็นสเต๊กนั้นก็มีตั้งแต่สเต๊กหมูพริกไทยดำ  สเต๊กไก่สไปซี่ (ราคา 69 บาททั้งคู่)  ฟิชแอนด์ชิพส์  สเต๊กปลาดอลลี่ (79 บาท) ไปจนถึงจานที่ราคาแพงสุดของร้านคือ Steak T-Bone (589 บาท)  และแน่นอน ทางร้านมี combo set สเต๊ก 2 ชิ้นราคา 109/119 บาท หรือแบบ 4 ชิ้นในราคา 209/219 บาท ครับ \r\n\r\nผมสั่งเสต๊กไก่สไปซี่ อาหารจานโปรดของผม เพราะร้านเข้าให้ไก่ชิ้นใหญ่ดี ไก่หมักออกมกำลังดี รสชาติก็ไม่ถึงกับจัดจ้านมาก (คงต้องเผื่อไว้สำหรับคนกินเผ็ดมากไม่ได้) แต่กลิ่นที่หอมฉุยและเนื้อไก่นุ่มๆ นี่แหละที่ผมติดใจนัก  มีขนมปังอบเนย สลัดหย่อมเล็กๆ และเฟร้นช์ฟรายเป็นเครื่องเคียง ปิดท้ายด้วยเป๊บซี่เย็นๆ อีกหนึ่งแก้วก็อิ่มอร่อยไปอย่างสบายกระเป๋าครับ\r\n\r\nเยี่ยมร้านเมื่อ จันทร์ที่ 19 ก.ค. 2553  19.20 น.\r\nจำนวนแขก\t30 คน  (50% ของ capacity)\r\nจำนวนพนักงานเสิร์ฟ 5 คน\t\r\nเวลาที่ใช้รออาหารจานแรก 11 นาที\r\nอาหารที่สั่ง สเต๊กไก่สไปซี่ + โค้ก\r\nจ่ายไป 90 บาท\r\n\r\nจุดขาย ราคาและการบริการ\r\n\r\nหนึ่งเรื่องประทับใจ\tเวลาแขกผลักประตูเข้ามาในร้าน พนักงานทุกคนจะกล่าวสวัสดีทักทายแขกว่า “หวัดดีค้าบ ขอเชิญค้าบ” ได้อารมณ์คล้ายๆ กับ 7-11 เลยทีเดียว\t\r\n\r\nหนึ่งเรื่องที่อยากให้เปลี่ยน\tถ้าร้านให้เฟรนช์ฟรายเยอะกว่านี้จะดีมาก (อาจจะเป็น option พิเศษเพิ่มเงิน 10 บาทอะไรอย่างนี้น่ะครับ)\r\n\r\n",
    "rating" : 4
  },
  { 
    "id" : 2,
    "reviewer_id" : 5,
    "reviewed_date" : "2010-07-31 15:00:26",
    "description" : "ร้านคิวซังราเมน เป็นร้านขายราเมนญี่ปุ่นที่ถุกที่สุดที่ผมเคยได้ไปเยี่ยมเยือนครับ\r\n\r\nการเดินทางก็ค่อนข้างสะดวก เข้าซอยพัฒนาการ 61 มาประมาณ 50 เมตรก่อนถึงป้อมยามก็จะเจอร้านคิวซังอยู่ด้านซ้ายมือ\r\n\r\nภายในร้านตกแต่งเรียบง่าย จุแขกได้ประมาณ 30 คน แอร์เย็นฉ่ำดี\r\n\r\nอาหารจานโปรดของผมก็คือ คิวซังราเมน ชื่อเดียวกับร้านนั่นเอง ราคา 59 บาท ทีเด็ดของคิวซังราเมน คือน้ำซุปที่รสชาติกลมกล่อมเอามากๆ ไม่ต้องปรุงอะไรก็อร่อยทานได้ทันที แต่ถ้าชอบรสเผ็ดๆ หน่อยอย่างผมก็ใส่พริกป่นไปซักหนึ่งช้อนชาก็เรียบร้อยพร้อมทาน\r\n\r\nเคยไปกินราเมนร้านอื่น ชามเหยียบสองร้อย ผมว่ารสชาติก็สู้คิวซังราเมนไม่ได้ (หรือว่าลิ้นผมมันไม่ไฮโซพอหว่า)\r\n\r\nยังไง ถ้าอยากได้ทานราเมนเงียบๆ ราคาสบายกระเป๋า ก็มาลิ้มลองได้เลยครับ มีเมนู ราเมนร่วมสิบกว่าเมนู แล้วก็มีอาหารทานเล่นพวกเกี๋ยวซ่า ไก่คาราเกะ ยำสาหร่ายซึ่งรสชาติก็สอบผ่านทุกจานอยู่แล้วครับ\r\n",
    "rating" : 4
  }
]
```

Note: Texts in description field are Thai language.

I have run following code.

```
data = pd.read_json("data/review.json",encoding="utf-8")
```

**Output:** "ValueError: Expected object or value"

```
data = pd.read_json("data/review.json",encoding="utf-8",orient='records',lines=True)
```

**Output:** "ValueError: Expected object or value"

```
pd.read_json("data/review.json",encoding="utf-8",lines=True,chucksize=1000)
```

**Output:** TypeError: read_json() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chucksize'
"

```
with open('data/review.json',encoding="utf8") as f:
     data = json.loads(f.read())
     data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Output:** "JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at: line 2110232 column 206"

```
with open('data/review.json',encoding="utf8") as f:
     data = json.loads(f.read(),strict=False)
     data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Output:** "JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 16591251 column 1 (char 544624441)"

How to import this JSON into pandas?

Note: My pandas version is 0.23.0.

**References:**

- [Reading Json file as Pandas Dataframe error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36837663/reading-json-file-as-pandas-dataframe-error)
- [ValueError: Expected object or value when reading json as pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44287011/valueerror-expected-object-or-value-when-reading-json-as-pandas-dataframe)
- [Python json.loads fails with `ValueError: Invalid control character at: line 1 column 33 (char 33)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295439/python-json-loads-fails-with-valueerror-invalid-control-character-at-line-1-c)
- [Add chunksize param to read_json when lines=True #17168](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/17168)
- [pandas.read_json documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.read_json.html)

Comment: Sorry, but this works on my machine with the two records provided. You must have malformed JSON somewhere else. Copy paste your data into http://jsonlint.com and see where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I found some users used quotation marks (") in the description field (https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwqqu.png). What file format should I export? I used to export data into csv format but there are some users who used commas (,) in the description field.

Comment: Your JSON is malformed. I have no idea how to help you. If the file was JSON lines, you could've salvaged something, but this is the absolute worst. Please give a kick to whoever you got this crappy data from.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This worked for me.

```
import pandas as pd
# Load the first sheet of the JSON file into a data frame
data_df = pd.read_json('reviewsclean.json', lines=True)
```