# Failed to transform json to csv

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I am trying to convert multiple records from json file to csv. I am getting the following error with this code.

**Error**

> ValueError: Expected object or value

**input**

```
{'longitude': [24.64977040886879, 24.65014273300767], 'altitude': [41.2, 34.2],'url': 'https://www.endomondo.com/users/10921916/workouts/392337037', 'userId': 10921916, 'speed': [9.0792, 13.284]}
{'longitude': [22.44977040886879, 27.65014273300767], 'altitude': [38.4, 39.0],'url': 'https://www.endomondo.com/users/10921915/workouts/392337038', 'userId': 10921915, 'speed': [9.0792, 13.284]}
```

**output**

```
longitude   altitude    url userId  speed
24.650  41.2    https://www.endomondo.com/users/10921916/workouts/392337037 10921916    9.0792
24.650  34.2    https://www.endomondo.com/users/10921916/workouts/392337037 10921916    13.284
24.450  38.4    https://www.endomondo.com/users/10921915/workouts/392337038 10921915    9.0792
27.650  39.0    https://www.endomondo.com/users/10921915/workouts/392337038 10921915    13.284
```

**code**

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_json('sample_processed.json', orient='records')
df2 = df1.to_csv(sep='\t')
df2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading Json file as Pandas Dataframe error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36837663/reading-json-file-as-pandas-dataframe-error)

Comment: I am afraid not. I tried that link before.

Comment: I think I got it, just need one confirmation, Is you input 2 different files or they are in same file?

Comment: There is no input2.

Comment: I have posted answer can you try and let me know if it's working?

Comment: DELETED my ans as it was not useful

Comment: Your JSON seems to be wrong, it should be either a list of JSON objects or just one JSON object.

Comment: Can you post the file somewhere?